# What is a "ynoate" in the context of alkynes?

Tags: nomenclature, terminology

In the literature, I have read the term, "ynoate" refer to a sort of alkyne. Searching through the IUPAC gold book and Google has failed to return an explicit definition.

Comment: You also hear ynamine, ynone, ynamides, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ynoate refers to a derivative of an alkyne acid. e.g. ethyl-3-butynoate  [structure here](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB6419574.htm)

The simplest of these is propiolic acid  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propiolic_acid

[image]

Comment: How is ynoate pronounce?

Comment: Ein.... oate...